# WebAPI: How can I make sure a controller will implement POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, interface

I am working on a WebApi service where I want to create different types of controllers. If a controller should implememt a POST method, then I want to have an interface IPostController that enforces it. However, what if my controller method needs to take a [FromBody] attribute of a specific type? How should my interface look for those [FromBody] methods?

I did create a method in my interface looking like this, but the idea that it enforces an implementation with an object type parameter makes me sceptical.

```
IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] object item);
```

This forces an implementation that looks like the following line:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]object item){ ... }
```

If I change the object to the class I actually want to use, I do not implement the interface method anymore.

Any ideas on what should be best practice here?

Comment: I am not sure. seem like you are trying to make things become more complex

Comment: @DanNguyen You mean that I should skip the interface creation?

Comment: Yes, why we need an interface for each controller class? Thinks simple to resolve complex matters

Comment: @DanNguyen: You are right. I think I was thinking loud when I wrote this. Thanks for the feedback!